# How to block PCs/Phones connected to my Wi-Fi Hotspot?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, network-manager

I create Wi-Fi Hotspot using `Network-Manager`. Now since everyone knows the my password, whenever I create Wi-Fi for my use(on phone), everyone connects to it which reduces the speed on my PC as well on my phone. Now is there any way to

1. Change `ssid/password` of my Wi-Fi Hotspot?

   or
2. Block some-one from connecting to my Wi-Fi hotspot?

I know the `IP` and `MAC-Address` using `arp` command.

I haven't tried `hostapd` yet. I will prefer to use Network-Manager to create Wi-Fi Hotspot. I am using Ubuntu 15.10(development branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

network manager -> Edit connection -> select wifi -> Edit -> Wifi-security -> change Key

or

change SSID or password key from config file

```
 sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi-name
```

Comment: Now I am the only one who is using my net :) .

Comment: thanks for accepting answer .  still if you face any problem share with us .

Answer (score 1):

You can see the connected devices using `nmap`:

```
nmap -O hotspotIP
```

-O detects the OS of the device.

Why not set up a password for your wifi hotspot, tell those that you allow to connect the password, and that's it.

Otherwise, you can set it up a MAC address filter, placing the MAC addresses of those that you allow to connect in the whitelist. Anyone not in the list is prevented from connecting...

Comment: How to setup MAC address filter?

Comment: @mnciitbhu This site provides some useful information: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/iptables-mac-address-filtering.html